# The broadcast created by NewHadoopRDD will not be removed?

Tags: hdfs, spark-streaming, broadcast

I want to read the files on hdfs by spark streaming. And I write some code like this.

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]");
JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, 
                                           Durations.seconds(batchTime);

JavaDStream<String> sourceStream = streamingContext.textFileStream(hdfsPath)
sourceStream.mapToPair(pairFuntion)
            .reduceByKey(reduceByKeyFunction)
            .foreachRDD(foreachRddFunction);
```

Everything is ok, but I found the RDD Block shown by spark UI will keep increasing.
Then I found the RDD Blocks are all the broadcast created by NewHadoopRDD

```
//A Hadoop Configuration can be about 10 KB, which is pretty big, so 
broadcast it
private val confBroadcast = 
                     sc.broadcast(newSerializableConfiguration(_conf))
```

My spark version is 2.2.0. When I change spark version to 1.6.2. The broadcast will be removed rightly.

So, is there some config I missed? or something else?
Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve this myself.

This is a bug for spark 2.1 & 2.2.

[SPARK-21357](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21357), this jira describes what happened.